# Updating array after each iteration

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following snippet of code which intends to update the value of the array "end" each time the if statement evaluates as true(in this case it equals to three). However, the array just gets superseded by the last update and all previous values are deleted. How can it be appended with the new set of values?

```
d.forEach(function (d) {
  if (d.state_type=="end") {
    end=d.user_ids;
  }      
});
```

Comment: [`end.push(d.user_ids)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: I tried this before posting the question, error message:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Then `end` either doesn't exist or it isn't an array.

Comment: `end` is infact `undefined`

Comment: OK, so I had forgotten to declare "end" inside the function. However, now although the values are getting stored, its stored as an object of 3 arrays. I want one single array containing the appended values.

Comment: `var end = d.filter(v => v.state_type === 'end').map(v => v.user_ids).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])` would be the es6 equivalent expression to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the `d.user_ids` array and push them into `end` one by one:

```
function whatever() {
  var end = [];
  d.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.state_type == "end") {
      for (var i = 0, l = d.user_ids.length; i < l; i++) {
        end.push(d.user_ids[i])
      }
    }      
  });
  return end;
}
```

Alternatively, you could do what you were doing originally but [flatten the array afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/1377002):

```
function whatever() {
  var end = [];
  d.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.state_type == "end") {
      end.push(d.user_ids)
    }      
  });
  var merged = [];
  return merged.concat.apply(merged, end);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezsGV/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
end.push(d.user_ids);
```

You also need to make sure that `end` is an array so your loop could be:

```
d.forEach(function (d) {
    if (d.state_type=="end") {
        if (typeof end == "undefined") {
            end = [];
        }

        end.push(d.user_ids);
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array `end` is undefined here.

You can add values in array using `Array.push(value)`.

```
var end = end || []; //Here I am just making sure if end array doesn't exist create one.

d.forEach(function (d) {
  if (d.state_type=="end") {
    end.push(d.user_ids);
  }      
});
```